# AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role does not get attached to role via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to spin up an EC2 instance with an access to the private ECR.

I have an AWS user (role) with permissions necessary to spin up the instance and do most of the operations setting up infrastructure:

- the `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` policy attached
- the `ecs:*` and `ecr:*` actions allowed
- the necessary `iam:...` actions (like `GetPolicy`, `AttachPolicy`, etc.; see below)

But every time I create this infrastructure, my service fails to start.

Logging into the EC2 machine via SSH, I can see the `ecs` agent does not start:

```
$ sudo systemctl status ecs

● ecs.service - Amazon Elastic Container Service - container agent
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ecs.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-11-16 05:59:28 UTC; 20min ago

...

[WARN] ECS Agent failed to start, retrying in 15.18926843s
```

The `/var/logs/ecs/ecs-agent.log` shows a tiny bit more information:

```
level=error time=2023-11-16T05:59:29Z msg="Error getting ECS instance credentials from default chain: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors"
```

No Docker containers are running on the EC2 instance (obviously).

After tweaking and running the [Amazon's self-diagnostic automation](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-instance-unable-join-cluster) (does not work out of the box, so had to fix the scripts to provide reasonable exception message and AWS credentials on the EC2 instance itself), I see the following output:

```
# download the `attachment.zip`; install `pip` and `unzip`; `pip install boto3`; put AWS credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`; edit `lambda_function.py` to provide EC2 instance_id and AWS region

$ python3 lambda_function.py

There is no container instance profile or correct trust relationship for the EC2Instance('i-02fcb0ded7fd5c8f2').
Before you launch container instances and register them to a cluster, you must create an IAM role for your container instances to use.
Amazon ECS provides the AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role managed IAM policy which contains the permissions needed to use the full Amazon ECS feature set.
This managed policy can be attached to an IAM role and associated with your container instances.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html
```

The user I am running `terraform apply` with has all the permissions to provision infrastructure.

The user I am trying to run EC2 instance with (and the ECS service) has the `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` policy attached via the AWS Console (by the admin). It also has all the ECS permissions (like registering in cluster, etc., via `ecs:*` and `ec2:*`)

I tried attaching the policy to the role and creating a IAM profile and providing it to the `aws_instance`, to no avail.

The `Infrastructure` tab on the ECS cluster page does not show any EC2 instances.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the policy not get attached or rather why the EC2 instance fails to even register itself in a cluster?

NB: the reason I did not go down the path of `FARGATE` is I do not want to mess with subnets and CIDRs - I want to keep this infra as simple as possible.

My Terraform script looks like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

# ----

data "aws_iam_role" "my_ecs_role" {
  name = "ecsTaskExecutionRole"
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "my_ecs_service_policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "my_ecs_profile" {
  name = "my_ecs_profile"
  role = data.aws_iam_role.my_ecs_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ec2_instance" {
  role       = data.aws_iam_role.my_ecs_role.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.my_ecs_service_policy.arn
}

# ----

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_all_sg" {
  name   = "allow-all-sg"
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
  }

  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

variable "public_ssh_key" {
  type = string
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "dev_ssh" {
  key_name   = "dev_ssh"
  public_key = var.public_ssh_key
}

# ----

data "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  default = true
}

# ----

data "aws_ecr_repository" "my_repository" {
  name = "relational-my-internal"
}

# ----

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name = "my-cluster"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "deploy_my_task" {
  family = "deploy_my_task"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "deploy_my_task",
      image     = "${data.aws_ecr_repository.my_repository.repository_url}:latest",
      essential = true,
      memory    = 1024,
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 8080,
          hostPort      = 8080
        }
      ]
    }
  ])

  requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
  network_mode             = "host"
  execution_role_arn       = data.aws_iam_role.my_ecs_role.arn
  memory                   = 1024
  cpu                      = 512
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_service" {
  name             = "my_service"
  cluster          = aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.id
  task_definition  = aws_ecs_task_definition.deploy_my_task.arn
  desired_count    = 1
  launch_type      = "EC2"
}

# ----

resource "aws_instance" "my" {
  ami               = "ami-0906a0047c1ebc062"
  instance_type     = "m6in.large"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b" # m6in.large is not available in all AZs

  key_name               = aws_key_pair.dev_ssh.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.allow_all_sg.id]

  associate_public_ip_address = true

  monitoring              = true
  disable_api_termination = false
  ebs_optimized           = true

  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.my_ecs_profile.name

  user_data = <<USER_DATA
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo 'ECS_CLUSTER=${aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.name}' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
  USER_DATA
}
```

Comment: Why are you using data source for the IAM role? Does it exist already or you want to create it?

Comment: @MarkoE user roles in my org are managed by an admin, so preferably one should exist already

Comment: Do you know that it exists or not? If it doesn't, then the admin should create it. Otherwise, the data source will return nothing, which would explain the errors you are seeing.

Comment: @ArpitJain I thought that is what `iam_instance_profile` is for? as far as I remember, there is no other way to set IAM role to EC2 instance?.. or do you mean the role/user which runs `terraform apply` (since technically they would be creating the EC2 instances)?

Comment: @MarkoE the role definitely exists, otherwise the entire `terraform apply` command would fail (tested empirically :P)

Comment: @MarkoE if the role didn't exist, then Terraform would throw an error when `terraform apply` runs. Terraform data sources never "return nothing", they either return the thing or they throw an error.

Comment: I don't understand this: "the reason I did not go down the path of FARGATE is I do not want to mess with subnets and CIDRs - I want to keep this infra as simple as possible.". Your EC2 instance has the same "subnets and CIDRs" as a Fargate task would have. Both EC2 and Fargate have the same VPC requirements. If anything, trying to manage your own EC2 instance and attach it to an ECS cluster is far more complicated than using Fargate.

Comment: @MarkB sure, it slipped my mind that `terraform apply` went through.

Answer (score -1):

**NB:** not really answering the original question, but solving the problem anyways.

---

Instead of using `EC2` launch type, I switched to `FARGATE` (as pointed out by MarkB in comments). Previously the issues with subnets were caused by me trying to define *new subnets*, whereas I could have relied on a *default subnet*:

```
resource "aws_default_subnet" "my_default_subnet" {
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "deploy_my_task" {
  family = "deploy-my-task"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "my-container",
      image     = "${data.aws_ecr_repository.my_repository.repository_url}:${var.my_version}",
      essential = true,
      memory    = 1024,
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 8080,
          hostPort      = 8080
        }
      ]
    }
  ])

  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  execution_role_arn       = data.aws_iam_role.my_ecs_role.arn
  memory                   = 1024
  cpu                      = 512
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_service" {
  name            = "my-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.deploy_my_task.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  depends_on      = [aws_ecs_service.mongodb]

  launch_type      = "FARGATE"
  platform_version = "1.4.0"

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = [aws_default_subnet.my_default_subnet.id]
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.my_sg.id]
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
}
```

This way, there is no need for a separate EC2 instance provisioning, so the infra plan indeed became simpler.

But this comes at a cost of needing to [allow command execution for the task](https://towardsthecloud.com/amazon-ecs-execute-command-access-container) and operating the AWS CLI in order to manipulate the instance (or rather Docker container on the instance).

Note: the public IP is required to pull the Docker images from public registry (DockerHub). This might also require opening port `443` in the security group.